# Log a message only when queue is full and purge the queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

We send a message to the queue using the @Gateway.
When the Queue is full, I dont want to log a message. Instead I want to log once for every 100 messages and ourge the queue.
Do we have any option to do this Spring Integration ?

```
//Send message to "INBOUND_CHANNEL"
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = Constants.INBOUND_CHANNEL_ERR)
@Component
public interface CustomGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = Constants.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
    public void sendMessage(Message<User> message);
}

//"INBOUND_CHANNEL" as QueueChannel
@Bean(name = Constants.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
public QueueChannel inboundFilePollingChannel() {
  return new QueueChannel(100);
}

//"INBOUND_CHANNEL_ERR" as QueueChannel
@Bean(name = Constants.INBOUND_CHANNEL_ERR)
public QueueChannel errorInboundChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel(100);
}

//Service Activator for "INBOUND_CHANNEL_ERR".
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Constants.INBOUND_CHANNEL_ERR)
public void handleErrors(org.springframework.messaging.Message<User> message) {
    // TODO: Log only when the "INBOUND_CHANNEL_ERR" queue is full for throttling and clear the queue
    LOG.error("Dropping the message. ...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why would one like to lose his/her messages, but there is some respective API. See `QueueChannelOperations` (the `QueueChannel` implements this):

```
/**
 * Remove all {@link Message Messages} from this channel.
 * @return The messages that were removed.
 */
List<Message<?>> clear();

/**
 * Remove any {@link Message Messages} that are not accepted by the provided selector.
 * @param selector The message selector.
 * @return The list of messages that were purged.
 */
List<Message<?>> purge(@Nullable MessageSelector selector);

/**
 * Obtain the current number of queued {@link Message Messages} in this channel.
 * @return The current number of queued {@link Message Messages} in this channel.
 */
@ManagedAttribute(description = "Queue size")
int getQueueSize();

/**
 * Obtain the remaining capacity of this channel.
 * @return The remaining capacity of this channel.
 */
@ManagedAttribute(description = "Queue remaining capacity")
int getRemainingCapacity();
```

You probably are not going to get an exception on every 100 messages because the queue capacity might be bigger. For that purpose you may look into a `ChannelInterceptor` to be injected into this `QueueChannel` where you can use an API I mentioned above.